# font awesome not working inside a tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I have this simple code. The font awesome is not working on it.

```
<a data-bind="click: someAction, attr: {id: 'sample-'+ $index(), href: 'sample-'+ $index()}, text: name" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <span style="float: right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></a>
```

I have the correct version of `font-awesome` installed. If I write the `span` tag outside of `a` tag, I can see the `plus` sign but I want the text and icon to be on the same line.

Comment: Do you have some error in console?

Comment: no error in console.

Comment: Try to delete span tag and add under a tag style float right

Comment: nope...it didn't work

Comment: try adding `clearfix` class or `display:inline-block; overflow:hidden` to your `a` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no option but to change the code:

```
<a data-bind="click: someAction, attr: {id: 'sample-'+ $index(), href: 'sample-'+ $index()}, text: name" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <span style="float: right"></span></a><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell without a live example, but my guess is that it happens due to the floating span. Try setting the span-tag to "display:block" or "display:inline-block". Does it work when you remove the "float:right"?

Answer (score 0):

Upper code is working fine with font awesome when i put this Link on same page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```